# type mismatch with some

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have following function definition:

```
def addMonoid[A](items: List[A])(implicit monoid: Monoid[A]) =
  items.foldLeft(monoid.empty)((a, b) => monoid.combine(a, b))
```

When I try to use it as follow:

```
add(List(Some(1), Some(2), Some(3)))
```

I've got:

```
Error:(35, 15) type mismatch;
 found   : Some[Int]
 required: Int
add(List(Some(1), Some(2), Some(3)));}
         ^
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Do you have an appropirate `implicit Monoid[Option[Int]]` in scope ? And... I suspect even after that `erasure` will cause a lot of nuisance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a `Monoid[Option]` is defined, and not a `Monoid[Some]`, cats isn't finding an implicit in scope. If you use the `some` syntax sugar cats provides which infers to `Option[A]`, this will work:

```
def addMonoid[A: Monoid](items: List[A]) =
  items.foldLeft(Monoid[A].empty)((a, b) => Monoid[A].combine(a, b))

addMonoid(List(1.some, 2.some, 3.some)).foreach(println)
```

Yields

```
6
```

Comment: But what I do not understand is `Some` and `None` is extend from `Option` (sum type, ADT), when I have a function that accept an `Option` as a parameter, then I can pass `Some` too, but why it does not work with monoid?

Comment: @zero_coding Because `Monoid[A]` isn't covariant, it is invariant in `A`. Thus, the relation "is subtype of" (`<:`) here, (`Some[A]` <: `Option[A]`), does not imply (`Monoid[Some[A]]` <: `Monoid[Option[A]]`).

Comment: Can a typeclass be covariant or is does not make sense?

Comment: @zero_coding Definitely. It all depends on the use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use Monoid directly in cats

```
import cats._
import cats.implicits._
Monoid[Option[Int]].combineAll(List(Some(1), Some(2), Some(3)))
```